# How can I toggle a dark theme for a stack of screens?

Tags: react-native

I have included a [snack expo here](https://snack.expo.dev/@priedejm/dark-theme-stack) that reproduces the exact layout of my project. App.js -> stack of screens. I am trying to figure out the best way to toggle between light theme and dark theme. I do not care for the ios dark theme setting to trigger this, for now, I just want the button to trigger it.

I would like there to be a button displayed on my home screen that when pushed toggles to the theme it is not currently on. I originally wanted to use *theme provider* to set my colors for each theme and then call that color on each page rather than the hard coded color but have failed to do so.

**When you have a stack of screens being called in a tab navigator, what is the best way to use a dark theme?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the [theme prop](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/themes/#using-the-current-theme-in-your-own-components) of the `NavigationContainer` **but your are still responsible for providing the styling for each of your components**.

That said, there are a couple of things we need to do here.

1. Let the button change the `theme` prop of the `NavigationContainer`.
2. Provide a custom styling (colors etc.) for all of your components depending of the theme.

We can solve the first problem by wrapping the `NavigationContainer` into a `ContextProvider` as follows.

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {
  DefaultTheme,
  DarkTheme,
  NavigationContainer,
} from '@react-navigation/native';

export const ThemeContext = React.createContext();

export default function App() {
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState(DefaultTheme)
  
  return (
    <ThemeContext.Provider value={{theme, setTheme}}>
      <NavigationContainer theme={theme}>

      </NavigationContainer>
    </ThemeContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

In your `Toggle` component you can then change the theme dynamically as follows.

```js
import {ThemeContext} from '../App'

import {
  DefaultTheme,
  DarkTheme,
} from '@react-navigation/native';

const Toggle = (props) => {
    const { setTheme, theme } = React.useContext(ThemeContext);

    return (
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setTheme(theme === DefaultTheme ? DarkTheme : DefaultTheme)}>
        
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
```

You will notice that changing the theme will not change anything in your current setup. This is because you need to take care of this yourself.

This could be done using either the context again or the `useTheme` hook. For your `HomeScreen` this could be done as follows.

```js
import { useTheme } from '@react-navigation/native';

const Home = () => {

    const { colors } = useTheme();

    return (
      <View style={{justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', flex: 1, backgroundColor: colors.background}}>
        <Toggle/>
        <Screen/>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

Toggling the button changes the `theme` now. You can access the default `theme colors` using the `useTheme` hook but you still need to apply it to your components. You could also provide a custom theme which is [done similar](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/themes/#:%7E:text=To%20pass%20a%20custom%20theme,prop%20to%20the%20navigation%20container.&text=You%20can%20change%20the%20theme,default%20theme%20will%20be%20used.).

Comment: This is exactly what I need. Thank you David. I have one question, where would I put the styling so I can access it? Am I making a theme.is file that holds the colors?

Comment: As I have written in my answer, you have two choices here. Either define the styling in each component via conditionals, that means you use the context again and write `theme === DefaultTheme ? {backgroundColor: “white”} : {backgroundColor: “black”}` or you provide two custom themes where you can define whatever you want and use it via the `useTheme` hook. There is an example in the link that I have provided: `const MyTheme = {
  ...DefaultTheme,
  colors: {
    ...DefaultTheme.colors,
    primary: 'rgb(255, 45, 85)',
  },` or whatever you want to define here.

Comment: Maybe another remark. What I usually do is to define a “theme.ts” file (js if you do not use typescript) and add my theme there and export it. The NavigationContainer handles the theme change and I mainly just use the “useTheme”  hook in my components. I do the same for font sizes, etc.

Comment: Thank you for your time david:)  I think I will go down this route!

Comment: You are welcome! Let me know if it works out for you :)

Comment: Do you mind editing my snack to replicate your answer? I have tried to get a basic example down but could not get it to work unfortunately.

Comment: Actually, I think I got it.

Comment: @JustinPriede Here is the snack: https://snack.expo.dev/@pgrepds/dark-theme-stack. I have only changed the background on the home screen for a proof of concept.

Comment: Thank you sir! Feel free to ignore this questions as you have helped me more than you know already! But if the toggle button was a React component, rather than a function, how could you call useContext?

Comment: Actually, `toggle.js` IS a react component, a `react functional component` to be precise. If you mean a `class component`, then you can not use the hook (since you can't use hooks in class components in general), but you can still use the context. If I am not mistaken, there is an example [in the react documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) for class components as well.

Comment: Awesome thank you! Last question:) What if I wanted to change the bottom tab as well with the same toggle button?

Comment: Since the `navigation prop` will be passed by the navigator to the `Home` screen, you can pass the `navigation prop` from `Home` to `Toggle` as a prop as well and then just navigate to the tab in the `onPress` function. If you do not want to pass it as a prop to `Toggle`, you can use the `useNavigation` hook.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243127/discussion-between-justin-priede-and-david-scholz).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest doing something similar to this:
https://www.section.io/engineering-education/how-to-control-dark-mode-in-react-native-using-redux/.

In the article the author uses React Native Paper to control what each of his screens look like. I personally have a theme.js file that has an if statement based on what my Redux state is set to. If it is to light mode, my global theme variables (e.g. background color, text color, etc.) are set to their respective light colors. When set to dark mode, my global theme variables are set to their respective dark colors.